# is there a way to write −= as one symbol in formulas

Tags: math-operators, relation-symbols

In programming `-=`, `+=` and other similar operators are quite popular. But I am unable to write such operator nicely in Latex equations.

For example when I use `x += \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}` I get the following formula:

[image]

The problem is that `+=` are kind of too far apart. Is there any latex operator which allows to write them closer together?

Comment: `\mathrel{+=}` should work (or `\mathbin`) depending if you want the relation space from = or the binary operator space from +

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for such a quick reply. I use this site to quickly write formulas http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php, and I am unable to use your expression. Sorry for a noobish question.

Comment: Problems with that site would be off topic here, but I can't test as it seems to be down I get `503 - Service Not Available` for any expression just now.

Comment: Another solution is to put `+` and `=` into braces: `\mathrel{{+}{=}}`. So you disable the natural kerning around the two symbol.

Comment: If you want to use `+=` as a relation symbol, which seems the right choice, you have to say `\mathrel{+}=` because TeX doesn't add space between relation symbols.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use

```
\[
x \mathrel{+}= \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}
\]
```

that will add no space between the + and the = signs and treat the whole block as a single relation symbol.

Of course a definition will do better:

```
\newcommand{\pluseq}{\mathrel{+}=}
\newcommand{\minuseq}{\mathrel{-}=}
```

and

```
a \pluseq b \minuseq c
```

would print

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The operators `+` and `-` in `+=` and `-=` should be relational operators as seen in egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258433/16967), because TeX does not set a space between `+`/`-` and `=` and the whole expression `+=`/`-=` becomes a relational symbol regarding the spacing before and after.

This answer tries an automatic solution. The `+` and `-` symbols are made active in math mode only. Then the active character can check, if it is be followed by the equals sign. If positive, the relational version of the `+` and `-` operators is used, otherwise the original binary version is taken.

A little additional work is needed to get compatibility with `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% save original binary + and - as \binplus and \binminus
\mathchardef\binplus=\the\mathcode`+
\mathchardef\binminus=\the\mathcode`-

% define relational + and -
\mathchardef\relplus=\numexpr\the\binplus + "1000\relax
\mathchardef\relminus=\numexpr\the\binminus + "1000\relax

% define active + and -, which check for a following =
\makeatletter
\catcode`+=\active
\catcode`-=\active
\def+{\@ifnextchar=\relplus\binplus}
\def-{\@ifnextchar=\relminus\binminus}
\@makeother\+
\@makeother\-
\makeatother

% enable active + and - for math mode
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathcode`+="8000\relax
  \mathcode`-="8000\relax
}

% patch \newmcodes@ of package `amsopn.sty'
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{amsopn}{%
  \patchcmd\newmcodes@{%
    \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
  }{%
    \let\std@minus\binminus
  }{}{\errmessage{\noexpand\newmcodes@ could not be patched}}%
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
   a += b + c \qquad x -= y - z \qquad \operatorname{foo-bar}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]